# Функция cos() выдаёт неправильный результат

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   double d = 50.879840;
   std::cout << cos(d) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Программа выдает результат *0.817144*, хотя на любом инженерном калькуляторе результат равен *0.630948*, и это правильно. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 16):

Функции `cos`, `sin` и подобные принимают параметр в радианах, а не в градусах.
Переводите значение из градусов в радианы, и всё будет правильно:

```
double d = 50.879840;
std::cout << cos(d / 180 * Pi) << std::endl;
```